# A question regarding the FTFGMPID. Show $\mathbb{Z}^2/\langle(a,b); (c,d)\rangle$ is finite and determine its cardinality

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules

The problem goes as follows:

Let $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ be two linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{Z}^2$. Show that the abelian group 
$$ G = \mathbb{Z}^2/\langle(a,b); (c,d)\rangle$$
is finite, and determine the cardinality of $G$ in terms of $a,b,c,d$.

It's related to the fundamental theorem of finitely generated modules over PID. Since $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ are linearly independent, form the vectors in a $2\times2$ matrix
$\begin{pmatrix}
a& b \\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}=:A$. Applying the theorem, we can find two invertible matrices, say, $S$ and $T$ over $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $S\begin{pmatrix}
a& b \\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}T = \begin{pmatrix}
d_1& 0 \\
0 & d_2
\end{pmatrix}=:D$, where $d_1,d_2\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $d_1|d_2$. We see that $\det A = \det D = \pm d_1d_2$. So $\det S = \pm 1 = \det T$. Then we have that 
$$G = \mathbb{Z}^2/\langle(a,b); (c,d)\rangle\cong \mathbb{Z}_{d_1}\times \mathbb{Z}_{d_2}.$$
It seems to me that $G$ is finite and $|G| = |\det A|$. But I am not sure how to prove it. Although I was told to consider for a particular case of the group, I still am having a hard time to come up a complete solution. Anything would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, you know that $|G|=|\det A|$...

Comment: @EricWofsey But I wasn't sure if indeed $|G| = \det A$ or not...

Comment: Well, what part of proving that are you not sure of?  It looks like you already have a proof...

Comment: @EricWofsey Sorry for the confusion. I wanted to prove that $|G| = |\det A|$. But I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: It looks to me like you've already proved it.  You proved that $|G|=|d_1d_2|$ and $|\det A|=|d_1d_2|$...

Comment: @EricWofsey Oh man, I knew I missed out something; I didn't realize that $|\mathbb{Z}_n\times \mathbb{Z}_m|=nm$. Got it now :P. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $G\equiv \Bbb{Z}_{d_1}\times \Bbb{Z}_{d_2}$, the order of $G$ is $d_1d_2$. Now, obviously, $d_1d_2=\det D$. Now, $SAT=D$, so $\det S\cdot \det A\det T=\det D$. Take the absolute value, and we get $|\det S||\det A||\det T|=|\det D|$. However, $\det S,\det T=\pm 1$, so $|\det S|=|\det T|=1$. Therefore, they cancel out and we get $|\det A|=|\det D|=|d_1d_2|$. Thus, in short, the order of $G$ is $d_1d_2$ and $|\det A|=d_1d_2$, so $|G|=|\det A|$.

---

Also, I tried to figure this out in an alternate way to validate your proof, but ultimately failed. However, I still think it's interesting. First, let $N$ be the normal subgroup generated by $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$. Then, let's consider the order of $(x,y)+N$, just to kind of explore the group. Eventually, we should get to some $(nx,ny)+N$ which is a linear combination of $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$. That gives us the following system:

$$c_1a+c_2c=nx$$
$$c_1b+c_2d=ny$$

By Cramer's Rule, the solution to this system is:
$$c_1=\frac{n(dx-cy)}{ad-bc}, c_2=\frac{n(ay-bx)}{ad-bc}$$

Now, $n$ is the smallest integer where these two constants are integers, so at the very least, we know $n$ is a factor of $ad-bc$. From that and the fact that this is a finitely generated abelian group, we know that the group is finite and thus it's going to be in the form of $\Bbb{Z}_{a_1}\times\Bbb{Z}_{a_2}\times...$. Furthermore, we know that $(1,0)+N$ and $(0,1)+N$ generates the group, so it's going to be in the form of $\Bbb{Z}_{a_1}\times\Bbb{Z}_{a_2}$ for some $a_1$ and $a_2$. (This has been proven [in another StackExchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2747715/finite-abelian-group-generated-by-two-elements).)

Now the proof linked above also implies that $|G/N|$ is the product of the order of $(1,0)+N$ and the order of $(0,1)+N$ divided by the order of $(G/N)/C$, where $C$ is the cyclic subgroup generated by $(1,0)+N$. Now, I don't know if it helps, but maybe it does. Anyway, that's as far as I got, so good luck with the rest.

Comment: That's just the fundamental theorem of finitely generated modules over PID. I have modified my question a little bit. I wanted to show that $|G| = |\det A|$, though.

Comment: @Alex Please see the top paragraph of my answer. Does that help?

Comment: @ Noble Everything above the horizontal line makes perfect sense. However, the paragraph below the line needs some deeper understanding of the topic, and I'm not sure I get it. But anyway, this solved my problem. Thanks!